# a good solution to set up a rdf triplestore in python?

Tags: python, rdf, sparql

i'm looking for something as easy and tidy as the ARC2 class for PHP to use in python.

so far i've taken a look at rdflib, but the lack of support for SPARQL and inaccurate docs are putting me off!

is there another python library which will enable me to set up and use a triple store quickly and easily, or am i stuck with using a traditional database for the time being?

thank for any advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I agree RDFLib is not great as a SPARQL engine and it doesn't scale much.

An option that always works for me is [4store](http://4store.org/) as a triple store with the Python client [4store-client](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/HTTP4Store/0.2). In the 4store IRC channel and [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/4store-support) you'll find helpful support.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new python [SQLAlchemy and RDFLib module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtuoso/0.6) for the [Virtuoso RDF  Store](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com) that is worth considering also ...